# ¿Cómo puedo hacer click en un boton en un canvas y usar un metodo de un script?. La intencion es pausar una escena en Unity

Tags: unity3d, canvas, botón, objeto

Tengo una escena con 1 objeto que se mueve y un canvas con un botón `play` y cuando ejecuto la escena el objeto se me mueve debido a que tiene asignado cierto Script con una velocidad y demás... Pero el botón `play` está en el centro.

Lo que yo quiero es que esté quieto todo y cuando le dé al botón, desaparezca el botón que sera con `button.setActive(false)` y que el objeto se mueva.

Estoy intentando acceder a los `scripts` para hacerlo pero no me deja hacer referencia a éstos y no quiero empezar a ponerlos `static` o no `static` porque me descordinaría todo, como se puede hacer para que en el canvas una vez le dé al botón play, se ejecute lo otro ? Dentro de la misma escena todo.

Una posible solución sería anular `1 script` y hasta que no le dé a "play" no ejecutarse ese script ( el del movimiento del objeto), pero cómo se hace eso?

Script para moverse el objeto:

```
public class MoveBall_ : MonoBehaviour {


public float velocidad = 10f;


private void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f) * velocidad * Time.deltaTime);
}
}
```

Lo que necesito es que esa `velocidad` sea 0 antes de darle al botón `play` que hay en el canvas , y al darle al `play` desaparezca el canvas secundario que he puesto (que creo que sé cómo se hace) y que empiece a moverse la bola tal como ese Script.

Comment: Es difícil porque va por partes pero bueno lo pongo ya.

Comment: Hecho @lois6b   :)

Comment: Resumiendo, lo que quiero es que mi objeto esté quieto hasta que el usuario no le dé al ``play``, cuyo botón está en el canvas.

Comment: Por que no pones `velocidad = 0` y cuando pulse `play` lo pones a `10f`?

Comment: Porque para hacer referencia a ``velocidad`` en otro ``script`` debo poner velocidad como ``public static float velocidad =10f`` es decir, **como estático** y al hacerlo, en un otro ``script`` llamado ``Contador`` tengo esta instruccion: ``GetComponent<MoveBall_> ().velocidad += 10f;`` y me sale este error: **No se puede tener acceso al miembro "MoveBall_.velocidad" con una referencia de instancia, califíquelo como un nombre de tipo en su lugar**

Comment: Es decir, al ponerlo como estático, me da fallo ahi jaja

Comment: Y por que no pones `velocidad` como propiedad a la `Ball`?

Comment: A qué te refieres? Puedes ser más explícito por favor?

Comment: No usaste Time.timescale ==  0?? mira esta función https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html Claro, esto tambien pausa la fisica del juego completo, todas las simulaciones y colisiones tambien se pausan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso se pude hacer de muchas maneras, pero como menciona el uso de un boton que esta en el un canvas usaremos este enfoque:

cambiamos lo que usted tiene como velocidad por `velocidad = 0f` y creamos un metodo que se encargara de poner la velocidad a `velocidad = 10f`.

```
public class MoveBall_ : MonoBehaviour {


    public float velocidad = 0f;


    private void Update(){
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f) * velocidad * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    public void Play(){
        velocidad = 10f;
    }
}
```

Despues en su canvas seleccione el boton busque el "componente" `Button (Script)` si no le aparece por cualquier cosa añadalo desde la lista de componentes `Add Component` busque una parte dentro del Script que pone algo como:

```
On Click()
List is empty

        + -
```

Pulse sobre <kbd>+</kbd>.

Se le mostrara algo como lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora pulse en el lugar que esta marcado con un `1` se le abrira un cuadro en algun lugar donde puede ver una pestaña con el nombre "Assets" y otra con el nombre "Scene" si el objeto que tiene el script esta en la escena busquelo en esa pestaña y si esta en assets pues lo busca ahi, y lo selecciona.

Despues de lo anterior en el lugar que esta marcado con un `2` selecione y le aparecera una lista con los "componetes" del objeto busque el script que tiene la velocidad me imagino que se llamara `MoveBall_` al pasar el raton encima del script se le aparecera una lista con los metodos variables ect accesibles para ese script, selecione el que tiene el nombre de `Play()` pues es el que creamos en el script.

Ahora al hacer click en el boton se "llamara" a ese metodo.

---

Nota: lo anterior tambien se puede emplear para variables, metodos con parametros ect, lo unico diferente es que a la derecha de lo que esta con un uno aparecer un campo para rellenar, en el cual pondra lo que requiera el metodo o variable.

**P.D:** Si podria directamente usar la variable para modificarla sin usar ningun metodo, pero pienso que de la manera anterior se entendia mejor, y cubria la tambien la parte de usar tambien metodos.

Answer (score 0):

La solución era simplemente en el Script poner velocidad = 0 pero había que hacer algunas maniobras con el `static` y `float`