# ¿Donde está mi error?

Tags: unity2d

En mi proyecto de Unity, quiero que de la escena de Title, al presionar un boton, entre a la escena Intro donde comienza el juego, pero antes hay un tutorial animado al centro de la pantalla que desaparece al hacer tap y entonces puedes empezar a jugar, pero no logro que aparezca la mecánica principal del juego o un `Debug.Log` que compruebe que leyo la instrucción de otro script.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

QuitarTutorial.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class QuitarTutorial : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject tutorialAnimado;
    public bool pausarJuego;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        pausarJuego = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.anyKey)
        {
            tutorialAnimado.SetActive (false);
            pausarJuego = false;
        }
    }
}
```

GeneradorColitas.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GeneradorColitas : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Camera cam;
    public GameObject barra;
    public GameObject colita;
    // una referencia para dirigirnos a la barra
    private bool juegoIniciado;
    private bool IrDerecha;
    private bool IrIzquierda;
    private float barraAncho;
    public Colita mycolita;
    public Score burro;
    public GameObject tutorialAnimado;
    public QuitarTutorial scriptTutorial;

    private float velocidad = 10f;

    void Start()
    {
        //tutorialAnimado = GameObject.Find("Tutorial");
        //scriptTutorial = tutorialAnimado.GetComponent<QuitarTutorial>();
        scriptTutorial = GameObject.Find("Tutorial").GetComponent<QuitarTutorial>();
        if (scriptTutorial.pausarJuego == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Generador");
            float barraAncho = barra.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents.x;
            IrIzquierda = false;
            IrDerecha = true;
            StartCoroutine (CrearColitas());
        }

    }
```

Score.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text puntosText;
    public int colitaValue;
    private int puntos;
    public Animator animator;
    public bool estaLlorrando;
    public GeneradorColitas gc;
    private float dancingSpeed;
    private AudioSource llanto;
    public AudioClip sonidoburro;
    public GameObject tutorialAnimado;
    public QuitarTutorial scriptTutorial;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //tutorialAnimado = GameObject.Find("Tutorial");
        //scriptTutorial = tutorialAnimado.GetComponent<QuitarTutorial>();
        scriptTutorial = GameObject.Find("Tutorial").GetComponent<QuitarTutorial>();
        if (scriptTutorial.pausarJuego == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Score");
            puntos = 0;
            estaLlorrando = false;
            llanto = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            UpdateScore();
            dancingSpeed = 0.8f;
            animator.speed = dancingSpeed;
        }

    }
```

Comment: bienvenido a stackoverflow, pude ser algo mas especifico en esta parte *pero no logro que aparezca la mecánica principal del juego o un Debug.Log que compruebe que leyo la instrucción de otro script.* yo lo que puedo entender es que quiere que despues de leer el tutorial se active algun script, pero por ejemplo esta parte **Debug.Log que compruebe que leyo la instrucción de otro script.** me parece confusa, quizas pueda aclaralo. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que usted busca poder comunicar una accion realizada en la UI en este caso al presionar un boton, dependera de muchos factores, por ejemplo si tiene el objeto que posee el script activo en la scena, por ejemplo para sino activarlo, si tiene que instanciar la escena o esta esta ya instanciada de fondo u oculta, si es una escena totalmente nueva ect.

Pero basicamente todo lo puede hacer mediante el control de acciones desde el canvas, podria podria usar una variable que determine cuando el usuario puede comenzar a jugar, o cuando pueda comenzar a jugar que el boton para ello se activara osea que apareciera en pantalla, y al hacer click en el que se llame al script que quiera, o se llame a un script que instancie la scena o lo que corresponda.

---

puede mirar esta pregunta/respuesta si lo que busca es algo similar a lo anterior:

[¿Cómo puedo hacer click en un boton en un canvas y usar un metodo de un script?. La intencion es pausar una escena en Unity](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/57453/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-hacer-click-en-un-boton-en-un-canvas-y-usar-un-metodo-de-un-script/66180#66180)

Por otro lado si lo que busca es una cominicacion entre script puede leer esta otra:

[c# pasar datos de una clase a otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61635/c-pasar-datos-de-una-clase-a-otra/63123#63123)

---

puede hacer esta prueba:

por lo que veo me imagino que usted tiene toda la scena instanciada asi que el codigo `if (scriptTutorial.pausarJuego == false){` no le funcione porque solo se comprueba en el `start` de seguir por este camino y no usar nada de los link mencionado, trate de hacer algo como esto:

```
    void Update () {
        if (scriptTutorial.pausarJuego == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Score");
            puntos = 0;
            estaLlorrando = false;
            llanto = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            UpdateScore();
            dancingSpeed = 0.8f;
            animator.speed = dancingSpeed;
        }
```

moverlo al `update`

---

Si no lo funciona trate esto:

QuitarTutorial.cs

```
    if (Input.anyKey)
    {
        //tutorialAnimado.SetActive (false);
        pausarJuego = false;
    }
```

y lo siguiente moverlo al update pero añadiendo esta linea:

```
    void Update () {
        if (scriptTutorial.pausarJuego == false)
        {
           //tomelo como psuedocode, pues pienso que con los link anteriores
           //podria hacerlo de una mejor manera

            scriptTutorial.tutorialAnimado.SetActive (false); //<-
            //..
```

y el resto igual que la primera prueba, tambien tener en cuenta que el update se ejecuta muchas veces por frame, asi que igual tiene que hacer algun filtro de lo que quiere que se actualiza y que es lo que no. O quitar algunas variables del update y dejarlas en es start como por ejemplo `puntos = 0;` pues me imagino que el player ganara puntos y si esta en el update se restableceria a cero en cada llamada, bastaria solo con dejarla en el start.